# Capistrano, Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm deploying first time with Capistrano, but I have few problems. At first, is it normal that all log lines are doubled?

```
$ cap production deploy
INFO [c2107197] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my-app/ on 123.123.123.123
DEBUG [c2107197] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my-app/
INFO [f3c2dd1c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my-app/ on 123.123.123.123
DEBUG [f3c2dd1c] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/my-app/
INFO [f3c2dd1c] Finished in 8.132 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [c2107197] Finished in 8.134 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. I had extra space in deploy/production.rb.

```
server '123.123.123.123 ', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app}
```

This caused task to be ran two times, as a release role of "123.123.123.123" and "123.123.123.123 " in Capistranos git.rake.